# Google Analytics data to display on my website / using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I need to display Analytics dashboard on my web site. Like export it from google's website to mine.
I already used Reporting API V4 
But I only get the login button.
[as you can see, the dashboard from analytics are not displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcdF2.png)

I need to do it with javascript or C#.

My code (based on [this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js) ):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Analytics Reporting </title>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="472734728686-21tqq751d9mdpkopnjmc1dnctf9644qc.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly">
</head>
<body>

    <h1> Analytics Reporting</h1>

    <p>

        <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="queryReports"></div>
    </p>


    <textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>

    <script>

        var VIEW_ID = '130082935';


  function queryReports() {

    gapi.client.request({
      path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
      root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        reportRequests: [
          {
            viewId: VIEW_ID,
            dateRanges: [
              {
                startDate: '7daysAgo',
                endDate: 'today'
              }
            ],
            metrics: [
              {
                expression: 'ga:sessions'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
  }

  function displayResults(response) {

    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  }
    </script>




    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking - your image shows exactly what the code is supposed  to do, displaying a JSON response that has been turned into a string. You'd need to replace the  displayResults function with something that formats the output into a Graph or Table of your choice.  You should look at Google Charts (https://developers.google.com/chart/) or another visualization library and get back with specific questions.

Comment: I'm sorry. Let me rebuild my question: How can I make it return the dashboard, not just a json?

Comment: How to do pagination in google analytics API.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you look at [Google Analytics Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/). It is much easier from a standpoint based on my experience.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  [I also found this one](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js "")